# How to match and find a specific element from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
const b = '2'
const numbers = ['1', '2', '3']
for(i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    number = numbers[i]
    if(number === b) {
        console.log(number)
    } else {
        console.log('Else')
    }
}
```

After running this code, I get this result:

```
Else
2
Else
```

But I only want to get the number 2. How can I do that?

Comment: Remove `console.log('Else')` or the `else{}` block? What is the actual issue?

Comment: You are correct, just remove else.

Comment: @AkshayBande I have removed the else block. It works. Now I have another question. If I change like this `if(number !== b)` and still I want 2 to be printed, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, you can just remove the second `console.log` to get the output you want.

Otherwise, the general solution to your question is like this:

```js
const b = '2'
const numbers = ['1', '2', '3']

const result = numbers.find(n => n==b)

console.log(result)
```